# Why IDE and console is doing different operation about xml files in Java?

Tags: java, xml, file, domparser

I am newbie in XML files operation. My program should do that when it is executed, it must generate random numbers and write to a XML file. Every time when I debug it in NetBeans IDE everything is okay, but when I try execute it in console with "Java -jar blablabla.jar" the XML files are not changing and I still see old values in XML files. Why is that happen? Why can IDE modify the values in XML while console cannot?

Here is my XML operations code block:

```
public class CreateXML {

public CreateXML(ArrayList<Integer> array,String name){
    try{
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db=dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

    String path="file"+name+".xml";
    File xmlfile=new File(path);
    if(xmlfile.exists()){
        xmlfile.delete();
        System.out.println("There was this file and it is deleted.");
    }

    Document doc=db.newDocument();

    Element rootElement=doc.createElement("numberList");
    doc.appendChild(rootElement);
        for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
            Element staff=doc.createElement("number");
            rootElement.appendChild(staff);

            Attr attr=doc.createAttribute("id");
            attr.setValue(Integer.toString(i));
            staff.setAttributeNode(attr);
            staff.setTextContent(Integer.toString(array.get(i)));
        }

    TransformerFactory tf=TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer t=tf.newTransformer();

    DOMSource source=new DOMSource(doc);
    StreamResult result=new StreamResult(xmlfile);

    t.transform(source, result);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The created file may not be where you think it is, try to print `xmlfile.getAbsolutePath()`

Comment: you are sure you running the same Version of your code if you run it from IDE and from jar?

Comment: @Berger i think it is not the problem point because IDE can find the file but .jar file cannot. So, I mean if the path is not correct IDE cannot find the file too, right?

Comment: @Jens Yes I am sure versions are the same. Because I click "Clean and Build Project" button before trying to execute from console.

Comment: @umtklc : You are using a relative path (since you don't indicate an absolute path for the file), I'm pretty sure the final absolute path won't be the same in the IDE and from the console.

Comment: @Berger So you think I should use xmlfile.getAbsolutePath() function ? Exactly where should I use it in code block?

Comment: `xmlfile.getAbsolutePath()` was just to demonstrate that the paths won't be the same.You may create your file with an absolute path, e.g `File xmlfile=new File("C:\\\\temp\\"+"file"+name+".xml");`

Comment: @Berger Actually i will sent the jar file someone else, so he should find easly the file and i should be sure about existing the directory that i point.  Sure about temp but maybe should find more easier place. How can i determine the place that .jar file is located ?

Comment: @Berger i will get over with that code " jarpath=CreateXML.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath().toString();" thanks for all comments.

Comment: Yes I was about to link this topic :) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file ,